# What is the equality theory, or equal transit time theory, and is it supported by scientific evidence?

Tags: aerodynamics

Throughout flight training when learning about the mechanics of lift I read and was taught this story about two molecules that part ways at the wing tip and reach the trailing edge of a wing at the exact same time. Later on I heard this referred to as the "equality theory."

The idea is that a wing makes a molecule travel farther to end up at the trailing edge at the same time rendering a greater velocity and a lower pressure through Bernoulli's principle.

I'd like to find the best articulation of the equality theory as well as information on whether scientific research actually supports it. Whether it's scientifically supported or not, it may at least serve as a useful teaching tool. In any case, if I talk about it I'd like to be able to cite something truly scientific.

Comment: Its called the [Equal Transit Time Theory, and its wrong](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/wrong1.html).

Comment: see also here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/16198/1467
here: http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/airfoils.html
and here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21664/1467
and: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8281/1467

Comment: It's interesting how this kind of stuff propagates. I once found a mid-20th-century textbook on the theory of flight that had a figure of streamlines around a wing with a caption saying this was how wings produced lift. The figure appeared to be an exact copy of one in an earlier, more mathematical treatment. The funny thing is, the apparent source had multiple diagrams of the wing showing different air flows we might conceive of existing around a wing; the one the textbook had copied was the "no lift" figure.

Comment: [Visual demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqexY7hObik) of fallacy in a wind tunnel (Youtube).